# Cannot read True Type Font FIle in my WPF APplication!

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, fonts

i'm developing a project in Wpf with Vista Sp1 on my laptop ,in this project i add some True Type Font that Windows Xp did not get  and when i debug my project on Windows XP i cannot see the True Font File,so i wish add in my project those fonts as resources but i cannot work out this step.
I followed all advices of MSDN but not luck...for example i added a Font File "INFROMAN.TTF" (this Font is a original Font File of Vista and stays in this directory C:Windows/Font) and in the textBlock i declare this line:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="./Font/#INFROMAN"> Test.... </TextBlock>
```

but i cannot see the right font.
Do you have any advice how i can add those True FOnt FIle as Resource in my project so when i run my project on the WIndows XP i can see the right fonts???

Thanks for your attention.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work out this stupid error in simple way:)

When i declare the directory of the Font Style i should insert the original name as Window nominate it  and not the name as Visual Studio denominate it for example : in my case i added in my project  the Font Style"Informal Roman" so in XAML i  need to write down as follow:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Font/#Informal Roman"> TEST.....</TextBlock>
```

and not the name that Visual Studio denominate in my project :

```
 <TextBlock FontFamily="/Font/#INFROMAN"> TEST.....</TextBlock>
```

Have  a good work.

Cheers